Invalid regular expression 'Trailing backslash' error on FreeBSD
I'm trying to use sed on a file.
My command is as follows:
sed -e 's/\-.*\ \ET/ ET/g'

This works fine on Debian but on FreeBSD I am getting the following error:
sed: 1: "s/\-.*\ \ET/ ET/g ": RE error: trailing backslash (\)

I also tried this one but it doesn't work either:
sed -e 's/\-.*\ \\ET/ ET/g'

Does anyone know how to make this work on FreeBSD?

Just remove those backslashes, they do nothing.

Adding to the comment of @oguzismail: You have Gnu sed on Debian, and BSD sed on FreeBSD. But while they are different, I would be surprised that the difference shows up in this way. Of course the backslashes should not harm, although they are redundant. The BSD sed man-page explicitly says: Other backslashes in text are deleted and the following character taken literally. Can you isolate a small, reproducible example (with a simpler regex having backslashes) which fails on BSD?

@user1934428 sed 's/\E//' causes the error in OP, must be a bug in FreeBSD sed.

@oguzismail I can't reproduce any of the errors on FreeBSD 10.4

@Fravadona I'm testing on FreeBSD 13.2. If memory serves sed didn't support \t, \n, \r in 10.4, perhaps the bug was introduced along with support for those escape sequences.

I see the problem also in 13.0 and 14.0. 12.1 is fine echo DEF | sed 's/\E//' gives DF

Why do you expect this syntax error to not be caught? What do you want \E to mean? If you mean just E, say that instead; if you mean \\E, that's what you should say.

On MacOS 12.7.3 (don't know which BSD this is based on), echo DEF | sed 's/\E//' also correctly produces DF. No syntax error here. The OP hasn't reported which BSD version he is using, and he still has not provided a reproducible example for the error. Also, it would help to know the shell this is running in, because there is one odditiy in the error message: There is a space after the letter g, where I don't see how this possibly would be produced.

You can always install GNU sed with pkg install gsed and use it instead of the base one.

echo "dfkjdfjkdjf" | sed -e 's/\-.*\ \\ET/ ET/g'works fine on FreeBSD 14. Plz provide full context/environment and input data. It doesn't comes from BSD sed.

Maybe it will be helpfully someone.
sed -e 's/\-.*\ ET/ ET/g'

